# Windows 10 automatic screen brightness option missing

Tags: windows-10, display, brightness

I have **Acer E1-571G** laptop with **Windows 10**. I was trying to follow the steps for *automatic screen brightness* like my MacBook from this [website](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/adjust-brightness-automatically-in-windows-10.html) but it didn't work. I have no options for automatic screen brightness

On Website Display Settings

[image]

***My Laptop's Display Settings***

[image]

Comment: Does your computer support it? Sometimes there is a gap in what Windows 10 can do and what the hardware is capable of. Also, some computers need a BIOS update for some Windows 10 features to work. Are you running the latest BIOS?

Comment: solution here: https://www.techjaspreet.com/windows-10-brightness-slider-missing/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to turn **On** the **Enable adaptive brightness** by following the below referenced instructions. Once this is enabled or turned on, you should then be presented with those options.

Additionally, you may be able to press the **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+Left Arrow** or **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+Right Arrow** to easily adjust the screen brightness otherwise.  See [Hotkeys And Key Combinations On Aspire One Netbooks](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3009/~/hotkeys-and-key-combinations-on-aspire-one-netbooks).

> ### [Adjusting the Brightness in Windows 8 or Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/107173/disable-windows-8s-adaptive-brightness-to-fix-dark-screen-problems/)
>
> Hit the Windows key, and then type in “**Power Options**” into the search,
>   which will pull up the Power Options panel.
>
> Once here, click the “**Change plan settings**” link on the selected plan.
>
> Then click the “**Change advanced power settings**” link.
>
> And now, browse down to **Display** –> **Enable adaptive brightness**, and
>   change the settings there to **On**.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.howtogeek.com/107173/disable-windows-8s-adaptive-brightness-to-fix-dark-screen-problems/)</sub>

Comment: still doesn't see those settings :(

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Have you checking in **Acer Quick Access** from the **Settings icon** that looks like a left and right pointing arrow, and then see if the **Adaptive brightness** is set to ON there? If that's the deal, let me know and I'll add to an answer for this with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Teamviewer which was messing with the video card, I uninstalled it and the slider was back again, also the function keys to increase and decrease the brightness worked back again.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> scroll halfway down **Display** for Windows HD Color settings -> to right **Video Playback Settings** -> switch on **Automatically Process Video To Enhance It**.